# Javascript: object is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

Let me preface with an apology if this is rudimentary for JS, it's been a while since I've had to do any coding in the language. Why am I getting a

```
 main.js:30 Uncaught ReferenceError: thisELem is not defined
```

in the code below (at the if statement)?

```
$('a.pb-menu-click').click(function(event) {

      var arrCollapseElems = document.getElementsByClassName("collapse");

      for (thisElem in arrCollapseElems) { 
          if ($(thisELem).hasClass('show')) { 
              console.log("found");
          }
      }

  });
```

Comment: Another option: `[...document.getElementsByClassName('collapse')].forEach(thisElem => { /* ... */ })`

Comment: Even better: `const found = $('.collapse.show'); if (found.length) { console.log(found); }`

Answer (score 3):

You just need the `var` as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) (or `let` or `const`, preferably).

```
for (var thisElem in arrCollapseElems) {
    if ($(thisElem) // also you had a typo here
}
```

It's easy to forget.

Comment: Actually you are looping through indexes, not elements

Comment: Or even `const`, preferably.

Comment: Sigh, thanks, it's been 7 years since I've touched this language.